# JS : innerHTML does not update

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple function to change the `innerHTML` of a span element.
here is the code :

```
function changeElementAnswered() {
    var dataq = this.getAttribute('data-num');
    var ele = document.getElementById('qp-' + dataq);
    if(ele){
        if(this.value != ""){
            ele.className = 'qp-item qp-item-answered';
        } else {
            ele.className = 'qp-item qp-item-unanswered';
        }
        var cele = document.getElementById('revq-' + dataq);
        if(cele) {
            cele.innerHTML = this.value.toString(); 
            alert(cele.innerHTML);
        } 
    }
}
```

and this is the HTML code :

```
<span class="test-answer-rev" data-num="1" id="revq-1"></span>
```

I successfully update the inner html of the span class. the alert function shows the correct answer but the problem is that the HTML code (of the current instance) does not get updated (can't see changes in Developer mode). What am i missing here ?

-- Already tried `.textContent` is doesn't work

**Update 1 :** I use the `span` in a popup which means the parent `div` is hidden (`display:none;`)

Comment: How the function is called?

Comment: What do you mean by _**"the HTML code does not get updated"**_?

Comment: @Mamun Its added upon 'window.load' with 'addEventListener'. First part of the code where class changes runs fine.

Comment: @Archer It means that i can't see the changes with my eyes :D

Comment: @KababChi Please share your complete code to provide you the solution as innerHTML looks fine as per this code.

Comment: @KababChi Please add your complete HTML

Comment: So what does _**"I successfully update the inner html of the span class"**_ mean?

Comment: @Archer It means that the alert functions shows the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry but this makes no sense.  It either changes what you see on the page or it doesn't.  You've contradicted yourself and haven't adequately answered my question.  If you *"successfully update the inner html of the span"* then what else do you need?  This has nothing to do with the alert.  Please supply a FULL **[mcve]** to demonstrate the problem.  It needs to be able to run and show us how your code is failing.  Post the code in a snippet (see the `<>` button in the editor) so we can run it.

Comment: Also, in your code what is `this`?

Comment: @Archer Yes, it doesn't make sense to me too. Look, i try to execute this code when a text input changes. eg. When i change the value of text input to `abc` the first part of the code which changes the class of certain element works fine. the second part where it changes the `innerHTML` works fine too meaning the alert shows `abc`. But when i look at the browser i can't see the change. It is supposed to change to `<span class="test-answer-rev" data-num="1" id="revq-1">abc</span>` but it remains the same and shows `<span class="test-answer-rev" data-num="1" id="revq-1"></span>`

Comment: @Archer `this` is the text input that triggers the function

Comment: [As you can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/1ezfbL40/), what you are trying to do does work.  You've not supplied enough information to reproduce your problem so we can't help you.  We can guess, but it would be better if you could show the relevant part of your code that causes you the problem, as nothing above does that.  We need a **[mcve]** that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` will make changes for the current instance of the web page only. It wont change the original HTML code in your file. If you go to developer tools and look at the HTML it will be changed, but you cannot manipulate the source file using `innerHTML`.

```js
function changeElementAnswered(e) {
    var dataq = e.getAttribute('data-num');
    var ele = document.getElementById('qp-' + dataq);
 
    if(ele){
        if(ele.value != ""){
      
            ele.className = 'qp-item qp-item-answered';
        } else {
        
            ele.className = 'qp-item qp-item-unanswered';
        }
        var cele = document.getElementById('revq-' + dataq);
        if(cele) {
            cele.innerHTML = ele.value.toString(); 
            alert(cele.innerHTML);
        } 
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="test-answer-rev" onclick="changeElementAnswered(this)" data-num="1" id="revq-1">gg</span>
<input value="a" id="qp-1">
```

Comment: I am not trying to change the source ! I am trying to change the innerHTML of the current instance. The problem is it doesn't even change in the Developer mode.